# How to get all options of a metafield in shopify in liquid file

Tags: graphql, shopify, liquid, shopify-app, shopify-api

I have created a metafield material in Shopify and it has a total of 10 options. And from 10 options user can assign one to the product now, I want all 10 options that the user can select. I can get the selected value by

```
{{ product.metafields.custom.style_reference }}
```

but I want all options in a liquid file

Comment: loop using the meta-field reference key.

Comment: Could you please give example with code for better understanding @Onkar